# builtins.AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'check_password'

Tags: python, flask-login

This a my aap.py file
If I'm providing a email and password which is unregistered then also they are able to go on /login page. Error is thrown in this line "if user.check_password(form.password.data) and user is not None:"
Any help will be appreciated.

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():

        user = User.query.filter_by(email=form.email.data).first()

        if user.check_password(form.password.data) and user is not None:

            login_user(user)
            flash('Logged in successfully.')

            # If a user was trying to visit a page that requires a login
            # flask saves that URL as 'next'.
            next = request.args.get('next')

            # Checking if that next exists, otherwise we'll go to
            # the welcome page.
            if next == None or not next[0] == '/':
                next = url_for('welcome_user')

            return redirect(next)
    return render_template("login.html", form=form)    enter code here
```

Comment: From which package did you import  User class

Comment: You haven't entered a correct user email i.e why you are getting user as None from db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python compiler moves from left to right, meaning that when it comes to checking multiple conditions with just the `and` operator, Python compiler checks the first condition first, and if it is true, it moves to the second condition, and so on for the subsequent conditions.

As a result, if you change the given line to something like below, your code shall start working as intended:

```
if user is not None and user.check_password(form.password.data):
```